# Ошибка CS1503 Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать из "Discord.EmbedBuilder" в "Discord.Embed"

Tags: c#

```
    [Command("profile")]
    public async Task SendRichEmbedAsync()
    {
        var embed = new EmbedBuilder
        {

            Title = "Hello dude!",
            Description = "I am a description set by initializer."
        };

        embed.AddField("Field title",
            "Field value. I also support [hyperlink markdown](https://example.com)!")
            .WithAuthor(Context.Client.CurrentUser)
            .WithFooter(footer => footer.Text = "I am a footer.")
            .WithColor(Color.Blue)
            .WithTitle("I overwrote \"Hello world!\"")
            .WithDescription("I am a description.")
            .WithUrl("https://example.com")
            .WithCurrentTimestamp()
            .Build();
        await ReplyAsync(embed: embed);
    }
```

Comment: я не на C# а на pyhon юзай данную библиотеку, но все же меня смущает то, что вы создаете EmbedBuilder, а не Embed

Comment: `.Build()` отдает вам совершенно другой объект, который вы не заносите куда либо. Пишите тогда `var mySuperObject = embed.AddField(...` и уже его используйте.

Comment: Написал, это - await ReplyAsync(embed: embed.Build()); и всё заработало.